# Microsoft Orleans, Unsupported type, Serializer not available GrainInterfaceMap

Tags: serialization, orleans

I am trying to connect to an orleans silo but I got this error.

> {"Unsupported type 'Orleans.Runtime.GrainInterfaceMap' encountered.
>   Perhaps you need to mark it [Serializable] or define a custom
>   serializer for it?"}
>
> at Orleans.Serialization.SerializationManager.DeserializeInner(Type
>   expected, BinaryTokenStreamReader stream)    at
>   Orleans.Serialization.BuiltInTypes.DeserializeOrleansResponse(Type
>   expected, BinaryTokenStreamReader stream)    at
>   Orleans.Serialization.SerializationManager.DeserializeInner(Type
>   expected, BinaryTokenStreamReader stream)    at
>   Orleans.Serialization.SerializationManager.Deserialize(Type t,
>   BinaryTokenStreamReader stream)    at
>   Orleans.Serialization.SerializationManager.Deserialize(BinaryTokenStreamReader
>   stream)    at Orleans.Runtime.Message.DeserializeBody(List`1 bytes)
>
>   at Orleans.Runtime.Message.get_BodyObject()    at
>   Orleans.Runtime.GrainReference.ResponseCallback(Message message,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 context)

When I searched in object browser, I can see a class, possibly created to serialize this class : 
[Orleans.Runtime.Configuration.OrleansCodeGenOrleans_Runtime_GrainInterfaceMapSerializer.OrleansCodeGenOrleans_Runtime_GrainInterfaceMapSerializer()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk5pn.png)

But somehow i got this error. I think there is configuration problem.. Do you have any idea about how i can solve this problem?
Thanks..

Comment: Could you please add which version of Orleans are you running?

Comment: Actually the problem was client and server orleans versions were different.  It is working now..

Comment: More details here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/1543